# How to load structured XML data into R?

Tags: r, xml, database, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a non-flat XML database that I want to turn into an R data frame. I parsed it as follows:

```
page <- xmlParse("<dataset>
  <language>
    <name>Old_Irish</name>
    <definite>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative</definite_source>
    <definite_article>1</definite_article>
    </definite>
    <n_cases>5</n_cases>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Irish</name>
    <definite>
    <definite_source>Demonstrative</definite_source>
    <definite_article>1</definite_article>
    </definite>
    <n_cases>4</n_cases>
  </language>
</dataset>")
```

I then converted it to a data frame as follows:

```
xmlToDataFrame(page, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,) %>% 
                        mutate_all(~type.convert(., as.is = T))
```

This is the result:

```
       name       definite n_cases
1 Old_Irish Demonstrative1       5
2     Irish Demonstrative1       4
```

But what I want this:

```
       name  definite_source     definite_article n_cases
1 Old_Irish   Demonstrative              1          5
2     Irish   Demonstrative              1          4
```

How do I create columns that are nested within `<definite>...</definite>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider binding both levels of nodes, assuming there is not more than one `definite` node under each `language`:

```r
df <- cbind.data.frame(
         xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(page,"//language")),
         xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(page,"//definite"))
      )
```